# Is there a Windows 7 shortcut to open Windows Explorer showing the Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, desktop

Is there a Windows 7 shortcut to open Windows Explorer showing the Desktop? I know that <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> goes to Desktop, but I want to see it in the Windows Explorer.

I also know that <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> opens the Windows Explorer, but unfortunately it opens it to the *My Computer* directory.

If there is no global default shortcut, what is the quickest way to setup one? I would prefer a simple way that doesn't require a third party program.

Which keyboard combination would you recommend using? I don't want to override a generic one or one that's already in use by the system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, create a shortcut to your Desktop. i.e. `C:\Users\%username%\Desktop`

Then see [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Create-keyboard-shortcuts-to-open-programs) on how to assign it a shortcut key, maybe <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> or something?

> - Locate the shortcut to the program that you want to create a keyboard shortcut for.
> - Right-click the shortcut, and then click Properties.
> - In the Shortcut Properties dialog box, click the Shortcut tab.
> - Click in the Shortcut key box, press the key on your keyboard that you want to use in combination with Ctrl+Alt (keyboard shortcuts automatically start with Ctrl+Alt), and then click OK.   If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

Use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) software and use a script just as this one:

A hotkey can be assigned to any of the above examples by including a hotkey label. In the first example below, the assigned hotkey is Win+N:

```
#n::Run C:\Users\%username%\Desktop
```

This will open your Windows Explorer on the desktop folder.